# Где в Opera хранится история?

Tags: браузер, opera, восстановление

Был краш opera. История пропала. Открытые вкладки пропали.

Есть ли в этом браузере что-то вроде временных копий старых открытых вкладок и куда ещё может записываться история?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нажмите на иконку Оперы, в левом верхнем углу -> Справка -> О программе -> в разделе Пути указана директория Профиля -> открываем директорию в файловом менеджере -> папка Local Storage -> папка leveldb -> файл MANIFEST-[указано число]  -> открываем файл с помощью Блокнота -> просматриваем посещенные ссылки.

Comment: Там есть папка Cache, в нем куча файлов без расширений, старые даты. И что дальше делать с этим?  Ммм

Comment: @anna, если в Windows включена функция создания точек восстановления, то можно попробовать правой кнопкой по папке - "Восстановить прежнюю версию", если открывшийся список не пустой, то выбрать нужный момент времени и нажать "Восстановить".

Comment: @insolor, я знаю, что так можно сделать. но увы... нету. Чем можно открыть файл History. Это файл истории в этом браузер так?